# How to copy an SVG and a link in the same clipboard item?

Tags: javascript, svg, copy

I have a website which displays a chart.

Below that chart I have a button which when clicked copies the chart as an Image to the clipboard.

I would also like to have a link to the website in the copied item, so that when the user pastes it to an email for example it will paste the Image and a link in one go.

Is this possible? Example drawing below:

[image]

Comment: How do you copy the svg now?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm using Highcharts for the below example.

Turns out the new Clipboard.write API cannot take multiple items. However you can get around this by creating a custom HTML wrapper element and copying that.

```js
// Get the SVG Element
const svg = chartRef.current.chart.getSVG(options);

// Convert that element into a data image: <img src="data:image/....
const asImg = svgToDataImage(svg);

// Create your new HTML.
const newHtml = `<img alt="A Chart" src="${asImg}" /><br /> <a href="some.website/chart/">Click to view this chart live.</a>`;

// Write the html to the clipboard.
await navigator.clipboard.write([
    new ClipboardItem({
        "text/html": new Blob([newHtml], {
            type: "text/html",
        }),
    }),
]);
```